# Getting Raspberry Pi or Arduino to control three clock hands separately

Tags: raspberry-pi, clock

I want to make an analog subway countdown clock. The idea is to have an ordinary clock with three hands. These hands will point to the number of minutes before the next, second next, and third next train arrives at my local subway station (one of the L stations in Brooklyn, NYC).

I was thinking to implement this using a Raspberry Pi. The software part is easy; however I have no idea how to get started on the hardware part. Is it possible to get a motor which can control three clock hands completely separately but on the same shaft? Or is there another mechanism that could address this problem?

I did some research, and you can buy hardware to control an hours-minute-second clock, but the problem is that you can't decouple the hands and get separate control on each of them.

Comment: Pull a centre-seconds movement (most quartz ones) apart, remove the train and the minute wheel. You now have 3 independent concentric hands. Drive the outer one via the hour wheel, the middle one by the cannon pinion, and the inner (second) hand directly. I'd use the hour wheel and cannon pinion from a second movement to give each a 1:1 drive (via idlers if necessary to reach the motors)

Comment: You will need custom gears and motors. A 3D printer or service may be necessary.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm interested in doing something similar and I'm wondering which suggestion you followed.

Comment: @isedwards I never did...

Answer (score 2):

You can use 3 successive hollow shaft stepper motors like this one: 
http://www.ebay.com/itm/CNC-Hollow-Shaft-28-2-phase-28HB3302K-Dual-Shaft-1-8degree-33mm-Stepper-Motor-/271809907038?hash=item3f4922095e:g:hwoAAOSwJkJWjO1P

Then use successively smaller shafts through the center of the one in front like this: [image]

Comment: Keep in mind that stepper motors are *incremental* devices which will need something to establish an initial position.  For example, an optical sensor at "0" and you independently rotate each through that while keeping track.  Or more crudely, weak motors and a mechanical stop at 0 which you stall each of them against.  You'll have to do this after every power loss, or any time you think your software's idea of where the hands are could have gotten out of sync with their actual position.